# Passing 'ValueError' & 'continue' in a function and call it

Tags: python, function, python-3.7, valueerror

I am trying to check user inputs to ensure that:
1) It is a floating number
2) Floating number is not negative

I am trying to put above 2 checks into a function and call it after user has input into a variable.

However, I cant seem to put 'ValueError' & 'continue' in a function that I can call. Is this possible?

I have tried below code, but it repeats from the top when I key in 't' for salCredit, or any of the next few variables. The code will work if I were to repeat 'ValueError' & 'continue' for every variable. I'm just wondering if there is a shorter way of doing do?

```
def interestCalculator():

    #User inputs required for calculation of interest earned.
    while True:
        try: 
            mul_AccBal = float(input("Enter your Account Balance: "))
            #checkInputError(accBal)

            salCredit = float(input("Enter your Salary: "))
            #checkInputError(salCredit)

            creditCard = float(input("Credit Card Spend (S$): "))
            #checkInputError(creditCard)

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")
            continue

def checkInputError(userInput):
    if userInput < 0:
        print("Please enter a positive number.")

interestCalculator()
```

## Expected results:

## Scenario 1: if user inputs 't'

```
Enter your Account Balance: 5000
Enter your Salary: t 
Please enter a valid number.
Enter your Salary: 500
```

## Scenario 2: if user inputs negative number

```
Enter your Account Balance: 5000
Enter your Salary: -50 
Please enter a valid number.
Enter your Salary: 500
```

## Current results:

## Scenario 1: if user inputs 't'

```
Enter your Account Balance: 5000
Enter your Salary: t 
Please enter a valid number.
Enter your Account Balance:
```

## Scenario 2: if user inputs negative number

```
Enter your Account Balance: 5000
Enter your Salary: -50 
Please enter a positive number.
Credit Card Spend (S$):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that continues prompting for input until a valid float is input

```
def get_float_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = float(input(prompt))
            if user_input < 0:
                print("Please enter a positive number.")
                continue  # start the while loop again
            return user_input  # return will break out of the while loop
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

mul_AccBal = get_float_input("Enter your Account Balance: ")
salCredit = get_float_input("Enter your Salary: ")
creditCard = get_float_input("Credit Card Spend (S$): ")
```

Comment: Hi Lain, thank you for your help!. How do I edit the code to show that if user inputs a valid number in creditCard, a new counter variable will be = 1. If user inputs 0 in creditCard, the counter variable will be = 0? This only applies for the creditCard variable.

Answer (score 1):

you need to `break` you while loop if all the input is successful (also note that the `continue` at the end of the `while` loop is unnecessary). and if you want to have a validation for every number separately, you could do something like this:

```
def get_float(message, retry_message="Please enter a valid number."):
    while True:
        try:
            ret = float(input(message))
            if ret >= 0:
                return ret
            else:
                print(retry_message)
        except ValueError:
            print(retry_message)

def interestCalculator():

    mul_AccBal = get_float("Enter your Account Balance: ")
    salCredit = get_float("Enter your Salary: ")
    creditCard = get_float("Credit Card Spend (S$): ")
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    def interestCalculator():

    #User inputs required for calculation of interest earned.
    while True:
        invalid = True
        while invalid:
            try: 
                mul_AccBal = float(input("Enter your Account Balance: "))
                invalid=checkInputError(salCredit)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid number.")
                continue
        invalid = True
        while invalid:
            try:
                salCredit = float(input("Enter your Salary: "))
                invalid=checkInputError(salCredit)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid number.")
                continue
        invalid = True
        while invalid:
            try:
                creditCard = float(input("Credit Card Spend (S$): "))
                invalid=checkInputError(salCredit)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid number.")
                continue


def checkInputError(userInput):
    if userInput < 0:
        print("Please enter a positive number.")
        return True
    return False

interestCalculator()
```